# Java : Need to get the same functionality of the Integer.toHexString() with a String parameter and not an Int parameter due to NumberFormat Exception

Tags: java, integer, numberformatexception

I have this line of Java code that will throw NumberFormatException if the number represented as a `String` is above 2,147,483,647.

**Because:**

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647

**Code Throwing the NumberFormatException:**

```
String largeNumberAsAString = "9999999999";
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(largeNumberAsAString)); // NumberFormatException
```

How can I get the same functionality of the`Integer.toHexString()` with a `String` parameter and not an `int` parameter due to `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: What about `Long.parseLong`?

Comment: `Integer.toHexString()` takes an `int` so I dont think that will work.

Comment: Then how about `Long.toHexString`? ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You should submit that answer. Seems legit.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth this is a cleaner solution. I prefer using `Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(largeNumberAsAString));`

Comment: I have made it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input value can be arbitrarily large, then [@dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657000/129570) involving `BigInteger` is your best bet.

However, if your value is less than 2<sup>63</sup>, then you can just use `Long` instead of `Integer`:

```
String dec = "9999999999";
String hex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(dec));
System.out.println(hex);                             // 2540be3ff
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/GvE1HW).

Comment: @javaPlease42 - FWIW, I'm not sure there's any difference in cleanliness between this and the `BigInteger` version - they both involve two method calls.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to avoid numeric limits of primitive `int` and `long`:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("9999999999999999999999"); // Default radix is 10
String x16 = x.toString(16);                             // Radix 16 indicates hex
System.out.println(x16);
```

The class conveniently exposes a constructor that takes a `String`, which gets interpreted as a decimal representation of a number.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ZsoBHR)

Comment: I would suggest that Long has a pretty similar method as what integer is providing.

Comment: @GhostCat That's right, using `long` would push the limit quite a bit further. However, the limit would still be there, and OP would have to be careful not to run into it.

Comment: I checked out the demo. Then I used https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html to verify the hex was correct. This seems like a good solution.

Comment: @javaPlease42 Yes, this is, in effect, a conversion from decimal to hex, limited only by the amount of memory available to your Java virtual machine.

Comment: Can you just update your answer to explain the `16` magic number please?

Comment: @javaPlease42 - Hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Integer.parseUnsignedInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html)

When the number is above 2^31 but below 2^32, thus in the negative int range,
you can do:

```
int n = Integer.parseUnsignedInt("CAFEBABE", 16);
```

*(I used hexadecimal here, as it is easier to see that above we are just in that range.)*

However 9_999_999_999 is above the unsigned int range too.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth quite right; I will add that mention. But the OP mentions the twos complement problem of int, and seems somehow to focus on ints. I alread mentioned 2^32, and it being a solution for ints above 2^31.

Answer (score -3):

Try this way:

```
 String largeNumberAsAString = "9999999999";
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(largeNumberAsAString)).intValue()));
```